# Where can I find exactly what each card status means in Midnight Suns?

Tags: midnight-suns

I've been having a lot of fun playing Midnight Suns, but I'd like to find a place I can see what all card statuses do rather than having to depend on trial an error. Where can I find what each card status in Midnight Suns does?

For example, the Hunter's Fury card - it has a status of "Final". Using trial and error, I've discovered it means that for the turn it's played, that's the last action the Hunter will be able to use. Not just cards, but they can also no longer move. Other characters are unaffected.

[image]

Comment: Mouse over the word?

Comment: I think you should answer this question yourself, and then go update one of the Wikis.  I too wondered what this did since the description was unclear.  I mainly wondered if it only meant for this turn, or for the rest of the mission.